# recommendations for good books focusing on the reward system, motivation and addiction

Tags: neuroscience, psychiatry, addiction, reward

As the title states, I would like to get recommendations for some good reads about the brain's reward system, motivation and addiction.
In particular I'm looking for a book that assumes no neuroscientific background, and possibly provides comprehensive overview of the brain structure, neuroscience glossary, etc.

Thank you